# How to properly call " void print_x(ostream& o) const" in main.cpp

Tags: c++, printing, ostream

I am writing my own vector.h class and I have a custom defined 
void print_x(ostream& o) const method it looks like this:

```
void print_x(ostream& o) const {
    o<<"[";

  for(size_t i{0}; i<this->sz; i++){
    if(i<this->size()-1)
    o<< this->values[i] << ", ";
    else 
    o<< this->values[i];
  } 
 o<< "]";

 return o;

 }
```

How can I call this function in my main?
I try to call this function in my main like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>
#include<algorithm>
#include<numeric>
#include<iterator>
#include<set>
#include"vector.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  Vector<int> v1{1,2,2,3,3,3,4};
  Vector<int> v2{1,1,3,3,4,2};

  v1.print_x(std::cout);
  v2.print_x(v2);

  return 0;
}
```

But it gives me an error like:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:29:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘Vector<int>::print_x(Vector<int>&)’
 v2.print_x(v2);
              ^
In file included from main.cpp:9:0:
vector.h:407:7: note: candidate: void Vector<T>::print_x(std::ostream&) const [with T = int; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]
  void print_x(ostream& o) const {
       ^
vector.h:407:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Vector<int>’ to ‘std::ostream& {aka std::basic_ostream<char>&}’
vector.h: In instantiation of ‘void Vector<T>::print_x(std::ostream&) const [with T = int; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’:
main.cpp:28:21:   required from here
vector.h:418:9: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
  return o;
```

Comment: In `v1.print_x(std::cout);` you call it correctly, why do you call it with a wrong parameter right in the next line (`v2.print_x(v2);`)? Also note, that the compiler warns you that `print_x` returns something, but is declared as `void`.

Comment: I am just trying with different ways to call it.  When I try to call only v1.print_x(std::cout) it gives out:  vector.h: In instantiation of ‘void Vector<T>::print_x(std::ostream&) const [with T = int; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’:
main.cpp:28:21:   required from here
vector.h:418:9: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
  return o;

Comment: so how should I do it instead?

Comment: I just don't understand _why_? You write a function with a defined set of parameters (one parameter of type `ostream&` in this case). Why would you try to call it with something else? What did you expect to happen? You already know how to call it, you've done it in the line above.

Comment: Concerning the other compiler warning, you might want to read up on return types. Short version: a function that's declared as `void` must not return any value.

Comment: Sorry it was just my bad, because I am not sure how to properly call it in main, so I was just trying out different things.

Comment: How can I print my vector using void print_x(ostream&)method then? Thanks!

Comment: You already did it! That's why I don't get the question. `v1.print_x(std::cout);` is exactly the right way to call it.

Comment: But it gives me an compiler error, so that's why I find it incorrect?

Comment: even if i removed the v2.print_x(v2); it's still not compiling.

Comment: That's because you read only half of the compiler warnings, I commented on both of them ;)

Comment: yeah yeah I understand, void must not return any value. But if I need to print something on the screen, how should I do it then.....

Comment: Correctly, I hope that solves your problems :)

Comment: Returning something has nothing to do with printing something. `o<<` that's were some get's printed to the stream.